# pandas: add row if column respects condition

Tags: python, pandas

dataframe

```
id            beg                       end     
guest1     2021-10-21 17:00:00       2021-10-21 18:00:00            
guest2     2021-10-21 10:00:00       2021-10-22 10:00:00
```

I want to test

if the client appears exactly one time and beg and end are not the same day then do like (guest1).
**col1** gets 2021-10-21 00:00:00 and **col2** gets **beg**

if the client appears exactly one time and beg and end are the same day then do like (guest2).

```
id               beg                   end                        col1                col2
guest1     2021-10-21 17:00:00   2021-10-21 18:00:00        2021-10-21 00:00:00   2021-10-21 17:00:00     
guest1     2021-10-21 17:00:00   2021-10-21 18:00:00        2021-10-21 18:00:00   2021-10-21 23:59:59
guest2     2021-10-21 10:00:00    2021-10-22 11:00:00      2021-10-21 00:00:00    2021-10-21 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use value_counts, callable indexing and isin to filter your data to only include ones with a single row and use another callable index to filter your data according to your greater than 1 day condition.

```
df[df['id'].isin(df['id'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x==1].index)].loc[lambda x: x['end'] - x['beg'] > pd.Timedelta('1 days')]
```

Comment: can you put the output of this query please? @alparslan mimorglu ?? im getting error when trying it **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'loc'** thank you so much

Comment: True, my bad. It should have been value_counts instead of nunqique(). Fixed it. Please check the solution and if it works accept it

Comment: now **NameError: name 'x' is not defined** can you put your output please?

Comment: there should have been another lambda. Now it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column to see the difference in days and then filter out what you need.

```
data = [('guest1', '2021-10-21 17:00:00', '2021-10-21 18:00:00' ), ('guest2', '2021-10-21 17:00:00', '2021-10-22 18:00:00' )]
cols = ['id', 'beg', 'end' ]
pdf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
pdf[['beg', 'end']] = pdf[['beg', 'end']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
pdf['n_days'] = (pdf['end'] - pdf['beg']).dt.days
```

```
       id                 beg                 end  n_days
0  guest1 2021-10-21 17:00:00 2021-10-21 18:00:00       0
1  guest2 2021-10-21 17:00:00 2021-10-22 18:00:00       1
```

Comment: Ok thank you then how should i do to add rows when n_days=0?

Comment: Why do you want to add another row?

Comment: i want to have the expected output like shown in my original post.

Comment: - the first row: col1 takes 2021-10-21 00:00:00 and col2 takes beg
- the second row takes end and col2 takes 2021-10-21 23:59:59.